# Angular project getting error after build in nginx in instance but running in local

Tags: angular, nginx

After I build the project in the server I am getting this error. Same when I am checking in local there is no error.

[image: Error]

this is hosted in nginx and the setting is

```
server {
    server_name  _;
    location / {
            root   /home/ubuntu/garage/dist/garage;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Check your JS files loading in Network tab. Server throws error or responds with default index page.